# Any real benefit to using PHP assignment operators to return code?

Tags: php, operators, variable-assignment

I've often seen PHP used to construct some arbitrary code in this manner:

```
add_action('wp_head','my_script');
function my_script() {
    $html = '<script type="text/javascript">';
    $html .= '//...a bunch of JS here...';
    $html .= '</script>';
    echo $html;
}
```

..but to me it makes more sense (just because it's easier to read) to do it this way:

```
add_action('wp_head','my_script');
function my_script() { ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    //..a bunch of JS here
    </script>
<?php }
```

Is there any benefit in doing it with assignment operators as shown in the first example above? Or is this one of those things that doesn't matter either way.

Enquiring minds want to know.

Answer (score 0):

i think its depends on how you use it. if you don`t want to close your php you can just directly use an echo. and i think it`s person preference if what you want to use.